# Speed measurement from lidar sensor for automatic braking system

Tags: sensors, c, code-review, uart, speed

For a school project I have been working on a system that will automatically brake when there is danger. Only the requirements are more strict (safety) than just using a ping sensor and detecting a fixed distance. I am going to implement the speed of an incoming object a swell.

On the internet I found this awesome 100Hz sample Lidar module that's very cheap. It uses UART with 2 header frames (0x59), after that a data Lowbyte and a data Highbyte.

So I've started inputting coffee and outputting code (in C) on the atmega328P (Arduino). Only I'm stuck for a few days now.

As you can see here I've set up the code to read the sensor and process the data. The problem is that it gives back weird readings, like a distance difference when I'm moving further away AND when moving closer even though I stated it not to.

Does anyone have experience using this module? Or maybe I misread something of the datasheet.

```
//Includes
//============================================================================================//
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <math.h>
//============================================================================================//


//Defines
//============================================================================================//
#define F_CPU 16000000                                          //CPU frequency
#define Baudrate 115200                                         //UART Baudrate
#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU / (Baudrate * 8))) - 1)             //UART Baudrate set in Arduino
// #define SafetyRating 8
// #define sampleTime 0x65                                          //Time between 2 samples in 10^-4. This value comes from testing (its 1,01ms)
//============================================================================================//


//Enums
//============================================================================================//
enum {Safe, Warning, Danger}State;                              //Possible States
//============================================================================================//


//Global variables
//============================================================================================//
uint8_t distanceL;                                              //Distance (low value) data taken from the UART buffer coming from Lidar
uint8_t distanceH;                                              //Distance (high value) data taken from the UART buffer coming from Lidar
uint16_t Distance;                                              //Distance combined
uint8_t frameByteCount = 0;                                     //To count which byte in the frame is current
uint16_t Speed;                                                 //Speed variable
//volatile uint8_t DangerLevel;                                 //Danger indicator


//Function prototypes
//============================================================================================//
void calcSpeed(uint16_t Measurement);                       //Function to calculate the speed out of distance readings
void UART_Transmit(uint8_t data);                               //Funtion to send data via uart
//============================================================================================//


//Interrupts
//============================================================================================//
/*UART receive complete interrupt*/
ISR(USART_RX_vect)                                              //Data taken from the UART buffer
{
    uint8_t sample;                                             

    sample = UDR0;                                              //Read a sample from the receiver buffer

    if(frameByteCount == 3)                                     //If its the 4th byte of the frame
    {
        frameByteCount = 0;                                     //Reset the counter
        distanceH = sample;                                     //Read the distance data high byte
        Distance = (8 << distanceH);                            //Combine the data low and data high
        Distance |= distanceL;

        calcSpeed(Distance);                                //Send the data to laptop for debugging purposes

    }

    if(frameByteCount == 2)                                     //If its the 3rd byte in the frame read the distance data low byte
    {
        distanceL = sample;
        frameByteCount++;                                       //Increment the counter
    }

    if (sample == 0x59)                                         //If a sample is a header increment a counter
    {
        frameByteCount++;
    }
    else if (frameByteCount != 2 && frameByteCount != 3)        //If its not a header or distance data byte reset counter
    {
        frameByteCount = 0;
    }   
}
//============================================================================================//

//Timers and Counters
//============================================================================================//
/*Timer0 Counter, this decreases the danger level periodically so a really slow approach will not keep incrementing the danger level*/
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)                
{
//  if (DangerLevel > 0)
//  {
//      DangerLevel--;
//  }
}
//============================================================================================//

//Main
//============================================================================================//
int main(void)
{
    DDRB    |=      0x02;                                       //For debugging purposes LED pin PB1 (pin 9) as output

    UBRR0H = (UBRR_VALUE >> 8);                                 //Setting the Baudrate register high value
    UBRR0L =  UBRR_VALUE;                                       //Setting the Baudrate register low value
    UCSR0A |= (1<<U2X0);                                        //Setting the data sample to double speed to make Baudrate error less
    UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ01) | (1<<UCSZ00);                        //Initializing UART, setting frame to 8 data bits
    UCSR0B |= (1<<RXCIE0) | (1<<TXEN0) | (1<<RXEN0);            //Setting receiver interrupt enable, transmitter enable and receiver enable... Transmitter for debugging purposes

    TCCR0A = 0x00;                                              //Timer0 Setup
    TCCR0B |= 0x05;                                             //Timer0 clock prescaler to 1024
    TIMSK0 |= 0x01;                                             //Timer0 overflow interrupt enable

    sei();                                                      //Set interrupts

    State = Safe;                                               //Set state to safe

    while (1)
    {
        //checkState(DangerLevel);
    }
}
//============================================================================================//

//Functions
//============================================================================================//
/*Calculate the danger level out of distance readings*/
void calcSpeed(uint16_t Measurement)
{
    static uint8_t samplenumber = 0;                                //Sample tracker
    static uint16_t value0 = 0;                                         //First sample
    static uint16_t value1 = 0;                                         //Second sample


    switch(samplenumber)                                            //To store the measurements alternately
    {
        case 0:
            value0 = Measurement;                                   //Store first measurement
            samplenumber = 1;                                       //So next measurement goes to a different variable
        break;
        case 1:
            value1 = Measurement;                                   //Store 2nd measurement
            samplenumber = 0;                                       //So next measurement goes to a different variable
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }

    if (samplenumber == 0 && value1 < value0)                       //When value0 is first and value1 is second and the object is closing in
    {
        Speed = value0 - value1;
    }
    else if (samplenumber == 1 && value0 < value1)                  //When value1 is first and value0 is second and the object is closing in
    {
        Speed = value1 - value0;
    }
    else
    {
        Speed = 0;
    }
    UART_Transmit(Speed);       //I think sending an uint16_t over uint8_t uart is possible because 'Speed' is never greater than 255 when i'm testing it
}

/*Send data over UART when buffer is empty*/
void UART_Transmit(uint8_t data)
{
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) )
    ;
    /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
    UDR0 = data;
}
//============================================================================================//
```

The datasheet for the module: [Datasheet Lidar module](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/benewake-tfmini-micro-lidar-module-ip65-12-m-datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Where is the datasheet?

Comment: I forgot to add the link to datasheet [Datasheet Lidar Module](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/benewake-tfmini-micro-lidar-module-ip65-12-m-datasheet.pdf)

Comment: First. Make `volatile` all global variables touched inside the ISR. Otherwise, it can be changed while `loop()` is using them. And as assignment is not atomic in Arduino, you can get *weird* values.

Comment: All `#defined` numbers should be enclosed in brackets to prevent against misunderstandings as a result of precedence rules.  i.e. `#define Baudrate (115200)`

Answer (score 1):

I found it!
Can't believe I was stuck for two days on this.

```
Distance = (8 << distanceH);                            //Combine the data low and data high
Distance |= distanceL;
```

Should be:

```
Distance = (distanceH << 8);                            //Combine the data low and data high
Distance |= distanceL;
```

Thanks all for taking the effort, and i'm definately going to do the experiment above to test the accuracy.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer to close this question.

Comment: I don't know how, because I asked the question with an guest account. And I made an account right after.

Comment: You have to wait 24 hrs (not sure) and then click the tick that appear at the left side of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are either getting interference that is corrupting the serial data or reflections from the scattering of the light off the object.

If you are certain that your code is right, which it seems to be, then I think you need to ascertain if the unit is giving you constant readings or not.  Can you set up a test that puts the unit at a fixed distance from a reflector and get readings for a minute.  The raw readings should all be identical, absolutely no variation.  They won't be they will waver around a tiny amount so work out what the percentage variation is for this distance.

Now repeat the test but at double the distance, you should get the same accuracy. Now again at double the distance again and you should have the same level of accuracy.

If the accuracy is varying "significantly" then you will need to generate a calibration table.  'At distance x the accuracy is y', etc.

Reflections will give you intermittent wildly inaccurate results. To combat this you might want to filter the data to remove any data that is more than n times the accuracy away from the previous reading.  n has to be a value large enough to cover the maximum distance the reflector (car) can cover in the time between samples.  I would guess assuming a maximum speed of 300MPH would be enough for most cases.